# Error with authenticationManager in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, spring-security

I'm developing an authentication service in my api through spring security(userDetails) and jwt.

Here the userDetailsService

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Services;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Models.UserModel;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.connect.model.UserNotFoundException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UserNotFoundException {
        Optional <UserModel> optionalUser = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (optionalUser.isPresent()) {
            UserModel userModel = optionalUser.get();
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userModel.getUsername(), userModel.getPassword(),
                    new ArrayList<>());
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
    }
}
```

auth controller

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Controllers;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Dtos.LoginDto;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Security.JwtAuthenticationResponse;
import com.api.business_manager_api.Security.JwtTokenProvider;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthController {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser (@RequestBody @Valid LoginDto loginDto) {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        loginDto.getUsername(),
                        loginDto.getPassword()
                )
        );

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

        String jwt = jwtTokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));

    }
}
```

In my auth controller I want to receive a jwt that allows my user to be authenticated through spring security. But my problem is in my securityConfig

```
package com.api.business_manager_api.Config;

import com.api.business_manager_api.Services.UserDetailsServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.AuthenticationConfiguration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorizeConfig -> {
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/user").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/auth").permitAll();
                            authorizeConfig.requestMatchers("/user/**").authenticated();
                            authorizeConfig.anyRequest().authenticated();
                        })
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

Previously I was having the following error after playing my application

```
Field authenticationManager in com.api.business_manager_api.Controllers.AuthController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' in your configuration.
```

however doing a search on the new version of spring security, i found that the solution is adding this in my code

```
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

but i am getting the error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'getAuthenticationManager' in 'AuthenticationConfiguration'
```

Does anyone know what could be a solution to this problem?

Comment: This is because you have wrong class imported: import software.amazon.awssdk.services.kendra.model.AuthenticationConfiguration;
Instead you need import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;

Comment: In fact, this import should not be there, but it is not being used. I removed it from there and it didn't change anything in my application

Comment: What error message do you have now? "Cannot resolve method 'getAuthenticationManager'" clearly says that there was a wrong import

Comment: You were righ. Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me why I can't access the "/user" route without falling into a 401 error, even though it's clear in my config that this route is a permitAll?